# subprocess Popen returns an empty string as last list member on communicate()[0].split('\n')

Tags: python

When I call a program with `subprocess.Popen` as the following:

```
input_file_new = subprocess.Popen('''grep -v '#' {} | cut -f 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 | \
        intersectBed -a stdin -b {} -wo | sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n |uniq'''.format(infile,\
        bound_motif),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')
```

I get a list of all of the lines from the output generated, with one extra empty string member as the last list item. I can remove it with `del` but that seems clunky. How can I avoid the extra empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `.split('\n')` into

```
rstrip('\n').split()
```

The last empty string is probably just a trailing newline!